# How To Create a Simple Floating Button without Javascript

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to replicate the scroll to top button on my staging website (https://staging2.nomadandinlove.com/) just by using CSS and HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `scroll-behavior` property, setting it to `smooth`. Although be aware not all browsers support this property. Here you can see the latest stats on this: https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-behavior

Also you will have no control over the animation. So if you need a solution that will work in most situations and that will give you more fine grained control on the execution of the scroll, use JavaScript.

```css
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }

body { width: 30%; }
```

```html
<a id="page-top">Top of the page</a>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>

<a href="#page-top" class="scroll-btn">Scroll to top</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The scroll to top button on my staging website actually uses JavaScript. It's a feature on OceanWP theme and works really well.

I'm reluctant to use JavaScript because I don't want to slow down website performance. That's why I prefer to use CSS. 

I would like to build the exact same replica of the button I currently have on staging, however I only want it to show when you get to a certain point from the bottom of the page. The button will be used to launch a chat app. If that is possible, can you recommend how I can go about doing it?

Comment: You don't have to be concerned with performance when choosing between CSS an JavaScript with regards to animations ([Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance)).

If you want to build your own button that appears on a certain distance from the bottom and will have to launch another application I think you have no other choice than to use JavaScript anyway.

With regards to your original question, this seems to be the correct answer so could you please mark it as accepted? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Much appreciated! I managed to create a simple button using the WPFront Scroll Top plugin. The plugin seems lightweight enough so I simply made changes to the code of the plugin to achieve my goal. It the lazy way of going about it but I saved myself a lot of time. Anyway, it seems be working quite well and I used JavaScript Async so it doesn't affect performance at all. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer close to @Terminator-Barbapapa, but if you don't want to create another element, just add ID to the body and link your button to the body ID as below:

```css
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }
body { width: 30%; }
```

```html
<body id="body-id">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac interdum lectus. Nulla feugiat et urna at ullamcorper. Nullam lectus elit, eleifend nec elit sit amet, tempus iaculis nibh. Sed non nisl tellus. Ut vitae rutrum metus, vel varius nunc. Nulla a mattis dolor. Quisque vestibulum quis ante sit amet blandit.</p>

<a href="#body-id">Back to top</a>
</body>
```

Comment: This might be more appropriate as a comment instead of a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The scroll to top button on my staging website actually uses JavaScript. It's a feature on OceanWP theme and works really well. I'm reluctant to use JavaScript because I don't want to slow down website performance. That's why I prefer to use CSS. I would like to build the exact same replica of the button I currently have on staging, however I only want it to show when you get to a certain point from the bottom of the page. The button will be used to launch a chat app. If that is possible, can you recommend how I can go about doing it?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are trying to attach a button in the end of your webpage which (onlclick) makes the user go back on the top..If so the code will be as follows-

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#to-here{
  height: 120vh;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="to-here">Want to come here ? Scroll Down then click the link..</div>
    <a href="#to-here">
      Goto Top
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

So basically i am using anchor tag "" to link to a specific point in web page. You can customize this anchor tag using CSS to make it look much more like a button. For more information of linking you can search for "Linking within a web page".